# /.store in, with default value in brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-pic

I would expect the following code to draw a red line, but it doesn't.

```
\tikzset{
ls/.store in = \ls,ls={draw,red},
myline/.pic = {\path[\ls] (0,0)--(1,0);}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (0) at (0,0) {myline};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I change the default value from "{draw,red}" to only "draw", it does draw a (black) line though. Can anyone tell me why I cannot set more complicated default values? Or, what is the appropriate way to pass arguments to a tikzpicture using keywords?

Answer (score 1):

While it is not necessarily best practice to store a style in a macro like this, you can make it work using the `style/.expanded` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
ls/.store in = \ls,ls={draw,red},
myline/.pic = {\path[style/.expanded=\ls] (0,0)--(1,0);}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (0) at (0,0) {myline};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It is arguably more Ti*k*Zy to just use a style right away.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
ls/.style={draw,red},
myline/.pic = {\path[ls] (0,0)--(1,0);}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (0) at (0,0) {myline};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can also just use `pic actions` here.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
myline/.pic = {\path[pic actions] (0,0)--(1,0);}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[draw=red] (0) at (0,0) {myline};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All the codes give the same output:

[image]

As for the question in the comment: yes there is. You can use pgf keys in a directory to control all aspects of the pic. Let's say we want to draw a house and control the color of its roof, the windows and so on. The intended usage is something like

```
\pic[draw=red] (my house) at (0,0) {house={roof style={red,thick},
    window style={top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue}}};
```

Then we create a subdirectory in which we store all the stuff. According to my experience it is also a good idea to define a shortcut for `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/house/...}` locally in the pic.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/house/.style={code={%
     % shortcut
     \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/house/##1}}
     % get the options
     \tikzset{/tikz/house/.cd,#1}
     \path[pic actions,house/wall] (-\pv{w}/2,\pv{h}) |- 
     (\pv{w}/2,0) --(\pv{w}/2,\pv{h});
     \path[pic actions,house/roof] (-\pv{w}/2,\pv{h})--(0,\pv{h}+\pv{r})
        --(\pv{w}/2,\pv{h});
     \path[pic actions,house/window] 
        (0,\pv{h}/2) rectangle ++ (\pv{w_window},\pv{h_window});
     \path[pic actions,house/window] 
        (\pv{w}/4,\pv{h}/2) rectangle ++ (\pv{w_window},\pv{h_window});
     }},
     house/.cd,h/.initial=1,% height
     r/.initial=0.5,% roof height
     w/.initial=2,% width
     w_window/.initial=0.2,
     h_window/.initial=0.2,
     roof style/.code={\tikzset{house/roof/.style={#1}}},
     roof/.style={draw,red},
     window style/.code={\tikzset{house/window/.style={#1}}},
     window/.style={},
     wall style/.code={\tikzset{house/wall/.style={#1}}},   
     wall/.style={thin,draw}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (my house) at (0,0) {house={roof/.append style={shorten >=-1mm,shorten <=-1mm},
    window style={top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue}}};
\pic (not my house) at (3,0) {house={roof style={draw=blue,thick},
    window style={fill=cyan}}};
\pic[dashed] (not even close to my house) at (6,0) {house={
    window style={xshift=-1mm,left color=yellow,right color=orange,shading angle=45},
    h_window=0.4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to do things like ```\pic[ls={draw,line width=2,green}] (0) at (0,0){myline};```

Comment: Is there a more TikZy way to achieve this?

Comment: the pic actions solution doesn't work for me because I potentially want to define multiple such keywords which affect different parts of the pic.

Comment: like ```\pic[window color=green, door size=5pt, roof style={draw,blue}] (0) at (0,0) {myhouse};```

Comment: @AndiBauer It absolutely is. I added an example. Actually I am using precisely this syntax a lot, probably for the same reasons.